# what is UPSERT statement in teradata and how it works?

Tags: sql, teradata

How the upsert command is different from update command and how it works please make me understand with example and syntax.

Comment: There's no `UPSERT` command, only `UPDATE ... ELSE INSERT ...`. It's a kind of predecessor of `MERGE`, see http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_015K/ch03.023.409.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UPSERT` command inserts rows that don’t exist and updates the rows that do exist. 
In teradata, it can be achieved using `MERGE` or `UPDATE-ELSE-INSERT`.

`UPDATE-ELSE-INSERT` syntax:

```
    UPDATE department
SET budget_amount = 80000
WHERE department_number = 800 ELSE
  INSERT INTO department(department_number, department_name, budget_amount, manager_employee_number)
VALUES(800,
       'Test Dept',
       80000,
       NULL);
```

`UPDATE-ELSE-INSERT`is a teradata feature.

`MERGE` syntax:

```
MERGE INTO DEPARTMENT USING
VALUES(700,
       '    Test Department',
       80000) AS dept(dept_num, dept_name, budget_amt) ON dept.dept_num = department_number WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET budget_amount = dept.budget_amt WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
VALUES(dept_num,
       dept_name,
       budget_amt,
       NULL);
```

Hope this will help.