# Similar Hash Algorithms in Teradata and Spark

Tags: hash, pyspark, teradata

I am performing an incremental load on data coming from a Teradata database and storing it as a parquet file. Because the tables from Teradata contains billions of rows, I would like my PySpark script to compare hash values.

Teradata Table:
[An example table from Teradata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWBNA.png)

Current Stored Parquet File:
[Data stored in parquet file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhsat.png)

My PySpark script uses a JDBC read connection to make the call to teradata:

```
tdDF = return spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:teradata://someip/DATABASE=somedb,MAYBENULL=ON") \
  .option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM somedb.table)tmp")
```

Spark script that reads in the parquet:

```
myDF = spark.read.parquet("myParquet")
myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("myDF")
spark.sql("select * from myDF").show()
```

How can I:

- include a hash function in my call to teradata that returns the hash of the entire row values (this hash should be performed on Teradata)
- Include a hash function in my PySpark code when reading in the parquet file that returns the hash of the entire row values (this hash should be performed in Spark)
- Compare these two hashes to see which is the delta from Teradata that needs to be loaded

Answer (score 1):

You want to Insert new rows, or, if rows with identifying info exist, update them. This is called 'upsert' or in teradata, ['merge'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547839/what-is-upsert-statement-in-teradata-and-how-it-works).

It depends on which columns are allowed to change and which ones make a row 'new'.

In your examples there you have :

```
terradata

    Name   Account  Product
    ------+--------+---------
    Sam    1234     Speakers
    Jane   1256     Earphones
    Janet  3214     Laptop
    Billy  5678     HardDisk

parquet

    Name   Account  Product
    ------+--------+---------
    Sam    1234     Speakers
    Jane   1256     Earphones
```

So if any Name,Account combination should be unique, the database table should have a unique key defined for it.

With that, the database won't allow insert of another row with the same unique key, but will allow you to update it.

So going by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547839/what-is-upsert-statement-in-teradata-and-how-it-works), with your example data, youe sql commands would look like:

```
UPDATE somedb.table SET product = 'Speakers' WHERE name = 'Sam' AND account = 1234 ELSE INSERT INTO somedb.table(name, account, product) VALUES('Sam',1234,'Speakers');
UPDATE somedb.table SET product = 'Earphones' WHERE name = 'Jane' AND account = 1256 ELSE INSERT INTO somedb.table(name, account, product) VALUES('Jane',1256,'Earphones');
UPDATE somedb.table SET product = 'Laptop' WHERE name = 'Janet' AND account = 3214 ELSE INSERT INTO somedb.table(name, account, product) VALUES('Janet',3214,'Laptop');
UPDATE somedb.table SET product = 'HardDisk' WHERE name = 'Billy' AND account = 5678 ELSE INSERT INTO somedb.table(name, account, product) VALUES('Billy',5678,'HardDisk');
```

But this is a very simplistic approach that will likely perform very poorly.

Googleing 'teradata bulk upload' finds links such as

- https://kontext.tech/article/483/teradata-fastload-load-csv-file
- https://etl-sql.com/6-ways-to-load-data-file-into-teradata-table/

There are likely many others.